# How to change cell properties in ParaView?

Tags: vtk, paraview

Following example model shows a cylinder with some cell properties on the left . The „ModelFaceID“ is a property that defines the different faces of the model. The faces are highlighted in different colors in the 3D view (right):

[image]

On the spreadsheet, I can see that each cell has a specific „ModelFaceID“, which assigns the cell to one of the faces:

[image]
Now, I would like to change the „ModelFaceID“ in a new model that has only one face yet. I would like to select cells manually in the 3D View and change the „ModelFaceID“ respectively, so that I get different faces for the model. Unfortunately, I cannot change the property on the spreadsheet. 
Here, a picture with my new model. I selected the cells in the 3D view (left) and the spreadsheet (right):

[image]

How can I change the property? Can I achieve that in ParaView? Do you have any ideas which other tool I could use?

You can find the cylinder example here (cylinder.vtp): [Cylinder Example](https://github.com/SimVascular/SimVascular-Test/tree/master/adapt_cylinder/polydata-tetgen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Paraview I would create a programmable filter and create a new Cell Data Array:

```
polydata = output
ids = [31,32]
array = vtk.vtkIntArray()
array.SetNumberOfComponents(0)
array.SetName("NewModelFaceID")
for i in range(polydata.GetNumberOfCells()):
    if i in ids:
        array.InsertNextValue(2)
    else:
        array.InsertNextValue(1)
polydata.GetCellData().AddArray(array)
```

According to [this post](https://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2017-April/039943.html) there is no easy way for obtaining cell id's from a selection in a programmable filter. What you can do is use an ExtractSelection filter and copy cell id's manually to the ids-list. Not very elegant, i admit.